# Автоматическая генерация счета-фактуры в PDF на PHP

Tags: pdf, php, html

Добрый вечер, господа! Пытаюсь сейчас решить такую задачу - при оформлении заказа в интернет-магазине нужно автоматически генерировать счет-фактуру в PDF. Решил делать так, делать или искать HTML шаблон счета-фактуры, затем подставляя нужные данные в шаблон генерировать из этого шаблона PDF файл. Возможно придется реализовать не только автоматическую генерацию счета-фактуры, но и других документов.

***Вопрос*** -  Где можно найти HTML шаблон счета-фактуры и других документов?

P.S. Решил использовать класс mPDF, после того как попробовал tpdf и tcpdf.

Comment: @eprivalov1, не знаю насколько будет приемлемо, но в Word-е есть некоторые шаблоны документов, а так же можно найти в инете шаблоны, не входящие в стандартный набор. Собственно, эти шаблоны можно сохранить, как веб-страницу. Способ не идеальный, но рассматривайте, как запасной.

Comment: А как мне найти эти шаблоны в Word'e? У меня стоит Microsoft Office 2003, но что-то пока не могу найти... Буду Вам очень признателен, если поможете разыскать ;-)

Comment: @eprivalov1, увы, но у меня сейчас нет времени на поиски, однако думаю, что [простой запрос в гугле](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=шаблоны+для+MS+Office) вам поможет ;)

Comment: @eprivalov1 а зачем вам счет-фактура? по-моему вы не туда забрались...  
Шаблоны для регламентированных документов можно найти в гаранте или консультанте.

Comment: Еще вариант, если есть 1С, то скопируйте шаблон от туда в Excel и как предложил Deonis, сохраните, как веб-страницу, но думаю есть и более лучшие варианты

Comment: @eprivalov1, расскажите, как вы в итоге решили эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE вам в помощь. На офф сайте, копируете с ворда, вставляете в демку, переходите во вкладку тоолс и копируете html код